# Providing video with unlimited length via ASP.NET Core webservices

Tags: asp.net-core, web-services

I want to make a video file available via an ASP.NET Core web service.

If I use:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public IActionResult Get()
 {  
     return File(@"videofile.avi", "video/webm");
 }
```

And access the video with vlc media player or a webpage like that:

```
<html>
<body>
<video id="video" preload="auto" width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="http://localhost:39589/mycontroller" type="video/webm"/>
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems that the video starts only when the complete file is transferred. I want the video to be transferred asynchronously, so that the video starts although it is not complete transferred.

Background: the video is constructed on the fly and will be in unlimited length (it will show the current time, so video is generated realtime in memory and should be transferred to web page every x frames). The goal is a webpage with a video which shows the current time live and infinite.

---

Edit: I got it working, I use a PushStreamContent object now.
When I use a mp4 (h264 codec) video now, the video starts playing although the complete video is not yet transferred (good, that is what I want).
But this seems not to work with a webm video (vp9 codec). Here the html video objects waits until the whole file is transferred. Is there a connection between codec and the behavior of html video player (e.g. if it starts playing although the file is not yet complete)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `enableRangeProcessing`.Here is a demo:

Action:

```
public IActionResult GetVideo()
        {
            var f = PhysicalFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\video", "1.mp4"), "video/webm", enableRangeProcessing: true);
            return f;
        }
```

View:

```
<video id="video" preload="auto" width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="https://localhost:44300/B/GetVideo" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

result:
[image]